# Trying to create default name system (e.g no name given by a user) for labels. Not sure about algorithms l have used

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, optimization

Users will be able to create labels in a list row by row **or** delete the **existing** by index. They will be able to give a name (in this question by name l mean a text in the label, not the widget name) to the labels.

The main task is the following: If no name has been given to the label (e.g. name=''), system should create an unique name for that label. Default names will be in the form (default_name_ + 'unique_index'). Unique index in simple words is the smallest possible non-negative unique integer. Hence if you delete few labels, some indexes will become free and will be used in the next no_named labels.
Test example:

```
create_label()  # uniq_index 0
create_label()  # uniq_index 1
create_label()  # uniq_index 2
create_label()  # uniq_index 3
create_label("new_name")
create_label()  # uniq_index 4
delete_label(2)  # free uniq_index 2
delete_label(2)  # free uniq_index 3
create_label("new_pin")
delete_label(2)  # delete new_name, so no free uniq_index
create_label()  # uniq_index 2
create_label()  # uniq_index 3
create_label()  # uniq_index 5
```

expected output name as a list (program will not need to execute this):

```
default_name_0
default_name_1
default_name_4
new_pin
default_name_2
default_name_3
default_name_5
```

(Window at the end should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTgPx.png))

I have tried to create a program, that seems to work, but not sure, if it will work for all cases. Also not sure, if that is the best program (probably not). Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font
root = tk.Tk()
big_font = Font(family="Roboto", size=20)
dict_of_names = {}  # elements will be as follows: {0: True, 1: False, ...} So 1 is an unique empty index
labels: list[tk.Label] = []


def create_label(name=''):
    if name == '':
        name = set_up_default_name()
    new_label = tk.Label(text=name, font=big_font)
    new_label.grid(row=len(labels), column=0)
    labels.append(new_label)


def set_up_default_name():
    name = "default_name_"
    for (i, is_used) in dict_of_names.items():
        if not is_used:  # if some values has been deleted
            dict_of_names[i] = True
            return name + str(i)
    name += str(len(dict_of_names))
    dict_of_names[len(dict_of_names)] = True  # new element add
    return name


def delete_label(index=0):
    del_item = labels.pop(index)
    name: str = del_item.cget('text')
    if "default_name_" in name:
        index = int(''.join([i for i in name if i.isdigit()]))  # need to get uniq_index
        dict_of_names[index] = False
    del_item.grid_forget()

    # update grid
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        labels[i].grid(row=i, column=0)
```

Extra tasks if user types a name that is not '' (not such important for now):

1. Names from user should be unique as well. Program will arise an error if name has already been used)
2. Lets imagine two cases, In both cases initially no labels exist yet.

   1. User give no name to label so default name is created
      by a program, so it name becomes "default_name_0".
   2. User decided to name it by himself and put name="default_name_0".

   Now he creates a new label with no name, so default name will be given to it by a program. In both cases name should be "default_name_1". In second case "default_name_0" will be created, if program doesn't have an algorithm to avoid this case.

I would like to know what is a better way of solving this, or what changes could be done to my code. I will be glad, if someone will try to write their way of doing this, if someone would like to do that.

Comment: _"I would like to know what is a better way of solving this"_ - How are you defining "better"? If what you have works, how would you decide if something else works better?

Comment: @BryanOakley In my opinion there are ways to make the program more efficient and smaller in terms of code that I wrote, maybe use smaller number of instances . As you know, there are planty of ways of doing the same task in programming. I thought someone could write something like "this way it does long operations, better to use . . ."

Comment: If you're only generating a few hundred labels, efficiency probably isn't as important as the clarity of the solution. I just want to make sure we address what you are really looking for.